# Domain based HTTP(S) routing with Google Cloud load balancing?

Tags: routes, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

Can Google Cloud Load Balancing route HTTP requests based on domain/subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is provided by "host rules" on the URL Map of your HTTP Load Balancing configuration. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/url-map#adding_host_rules for documentation.